# Ajax Request always fire error even when json_encode is right and everything work as it should

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm doing an e-commerce and I implemented an AJAX request to add and remove items from the cart dinamically. Everytime the jQuery is executed **everything works fine**, It always returns **200 OK** but the error event is fired instead of success.

**That's how it works:**

Everytime the user click the **"Add to Cart"** button, the Jquery will check if this item is available, then will INSERT, ADD or Return Error:

- **Status 1** = Product Inserted into Cart (Empty Cart, First time this product is added)
- **Status 2** = Product added to Cart (This product is already on Cart, add +1)
- **Status 3** = Not Enough Stock (All the products already on Cart)

**jQUERY CODE**

```
$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "addCart.php",
    data: { id: id, color: color },
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(result){ 
        if (result.status == 1){ alert("Product Inserted into Cart"); }
        if (result.status == 2){ alert("Product Added to Cart"); }
        if (result.status == 3){ alert("Not enough Stock"); }
    },

    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseText)
    }   

});
```

**PHP CODE (addCart.php)**

```
## I REMOVED NON-RELEVANT CODES TO SIMPLIFY THIS QUESTION BUT ALL VALIDATIONS
## HAVE ALREADY BEEN DONE, THEN RETURN THE JSON RESPONSE...

if ($status == 1){
    $status_txt = "Product Inserted into Cart";

}elseif ($status == 2){
    $status_txt = "Product Added to Cart";

}elseif ($status == 3){
    $status_txt = "Not enough stock";

}

echo json_encode(array("status" => $status, "alert" => $status_txt));
```

Every time the code is executed everything works as it should, the items are added to the cart, all the INSERTS and UPDATES are done, it always returns 200 OK **BUT** the error event is fired instead of success.

**IMPORTANT ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

The strings **$status** and **$status_txt** (addCart.php) never return empty values, they always return an integer and a text message. To avoid empty values (**""**) parse error.

**THINGS I ALREADY TRIED BUT DID NOT WORK: //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

- Remove (dataType: "json")
- Change the dataType: "json" to "text"
- Force a Header ('Content-Type: application / json');
- Use exit (); after json_encode
- Check if my JSON is valid or not on external sites, ie: [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

I've managed an workaround that temporarily fix my problem. I used Javascript **substr()**, to get the Status number on error **responseText** and then made all the validations on the Ajax Error Event:

**JAVASCRIPT WORKAROUND**

```
    error: function (result) {

        status = result.responseText.substr(10, 1); 
        if (status == 1){ alert("Product Inserted into Cart"); }
        if (status == 2){ alert("Product Added to Cart"); }
        if (status == 3){ alert("Not enough Stock"); }

    }
```

Where **responseText** return the Json result:

```
{"status":1,"alert":"Product inserted to Cart"}
```

And using **substr()** will return the status number (1, 2 or 3):

```
status = result.responseText.substr(10, 1);
```

I know it's not the right way to handle this, that's why I want to fix this error that's driving me nuts...

What I'm doing wrong? I've used this code several times and I've never had this problem before, I've read tons of similar questions here on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what does `alert(result.responseText)` alert?

Comment: Can you show this in reality? jsfiddle? site upload? Du you set the responsetype in the php file via `header(...)`?

Comment: Look in your browser's *Network* console for the AJAX request. What does the response headers and data look like? Perhaps post some screenshots

Comment: OT: Better way: Don't return statuscodes like you do and always 200 OK. Use the http statuscodes, like you would do in an api. 200 OK only if it was successfully added to the cart. Errorcodes in the other cases.

Comment: and: why do you use `status = result.responseText.substr(10, 1); ` instead of `JSON.parse(status = result.responseText).status`?

Comment: At a guess, your response body is invalid JSON. The reason you're not seeing it is because you are omitting some vital information in your error handler. Try `error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown) }`. I bet you see "parsererror" followed by some very useful information

Comment: I'd be looking closely at your PHP. You don't want any `echo` statements or accidental output before or after your `echo json_encode(...)` line. This includes checking for [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that your IDE or editor may have inserted at the beginning of your PHP scripts.

Comment: It seems suicidal to have a go at this question :) But I'll try - I honestly think you are not passing the right `id` and `color` variables, and that's what all the issue is. Show us how you define `id` and  `color` variables before the AJAX call.

Comment: @Aydin it wouldn't even get to the `error` handler if that were the case

Comment: That's true Phil. I cannot replicate his error. I guess he should follow your comment and spit out the full error info.

Comment: @Phil You're right, I used your error handler and got `parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. I'm also look closely at my Php and didn't find any echo or output before or after json_echo... When I use `alert(result.responseText)` I get `Array{"status":1,"alert":"Product Inserted"}`. I Still didn't find what this unexpected character is but i'm working on it...

Comment: @suicidebilly Your output literally has `Array` at the start? Looks like at some point your using `echo $somePHPArray;` prior to `echo json_encode...`

Comment: @Phil Yes, my `response` output has `Array` at the start... The only echo on my php is `echo json_encode(array("status" => $status, "alert" => $status_txt));` I've checked the json_encode manual and it's a valid use of an array... The product color is a hexadecimal value, `#000000`, maybe the # is the problem?

Comment: It most certainly should not have "Array", that's making your JSON invalid. Check your PHP **very carefully** for any `echo`, `<?=` or `print` statements that are not `echo json_encode...`

Comment: @suicidebilly Also, at the top of your PHP script, set `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. That will point out where you're attempting to perform an array to string conversion via a warning in the response body

Comment: @Phil I've double checked and there is no `echo` `<?=` or `print` on my code, only a commented test echo `//echo $_SESSION['user']`. I deleted this echo just in case but the error persist. However I used `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` as you stated and got `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in ... on line 30`. This line have a PDO Statement Fetch `$user = $stmt->fetch();`. If I remove the whole statement block the code works and the error is not fired...

Comment: @Phil The strange thing is that I have a similar update statement bellow this line that work without a problem... Don't know why tought but you certainly give me a direction... I'm still working on it, if you have any suggestions...

Comment: Without seeing the code, I don't know. Make sure the script you're looking at is the same as the one running on your server

Comment: @Phil Just found the error! An `$stmt->bindParam` had a wrong value, causing the string to be outputed as `Array` before the json_encode, as you stated. Your tips with `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown) }` were essential to help me find the error... Everything is working now! If you put this two suggestions into an Answer I'll accept the Answer. Thanks Mate!

Comment: @suicidebilly done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON response body is invalid. This can be seen in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851477/ajax-request-always-fire-error-even-when-json-encode-is-right-and-everything-wor/45854160#comment78663792_45851477)...

> I get `Array{"status":1,"alert":"Product Inserted"}`

That "Array" prefix is not valid and is typically an indicator of accidental array-to-string conversion in PHP, prior to where you `echo` JSON. For example

```
echo [1,2,3]; // Notice: Array to string conversion in ...
```

When developing, you should **always** run PHP with error-reporting set to the highest level. Displaying errors in your output is also the quickest way to be alerted.

You have two options...

1. In your development environment's `php.ini` file, set

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL
   ```

   and

   ```
   display_errors = On
   ```
2. In your code

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```

This should help you track down any accidental output (which it did).

---

Also, you were missing out on **vital** information in your client-side error handler. The signature for the callback is

```
Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

You can gain some valuable insight with something as simple as

```
console.error(textStatus, errorThrown)
```

Comment: That's it, your tips were essential to help me find the error... Not only for this problem itself but I've learned things that I never used before. Thanks Again!

Answer (score -3):

worked for me

**addCart.php**

```
<?php
// your inserts and checking here.    
$str = json_encode(array("status" => $status, "alert" => $status_txt));
echo $str;
```

and in the AJAX request

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/addCart.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { id: id, color: color },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res){
     console.log(res['status']);
     if (res['status'] == 1) {
       console.log('nice');
     }
  },
  error: function(s) {
     console.log(s.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: success handler isn't called. So your answer is not part of the problem and useless.

Comment: worked for me, changed the dataType to json. and in the php file, just echo the json. tried it on my server.

Comment: `res['status'] == 1` and `res.status == 1` are functionally identical